# Context menu in Ckfinder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckfinder

I am using ckfinder for ckeditor in asp.net mvc.
I want to change font of context menu in ckfinder, but I can't inspect that in chrome to find css code.
How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try to open dev tools on CKFinder popup window - it will have separate dev tools because it is a new window.

Comment: @jodator : Yes, when I open dev tools in popup window, context menu is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using CKFinder 2.x this requires some browsing through the DOM.

1. Open dev tools on popup
2. Open DOM inspector (Elements tab)
3. Browse to the iframe that holds contents of the CKFinder
4. Collapse whole `div#ckfinder` that is just inside body of that iframe
5. After opening a context menu you'll notice a node below `div#ckfinder` like this: `<div class="cke_skin_kama skin_kama cke_compatibility">..</div>`

That div is holding contextmenu. To show it just disable CSS style `display: none`.

You'll need to update `skins/kama/uipanel.css` to change `.cke_skin_kama .cke_menuitem a` definition.